# RigidBody AddForce not work with rb.velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void MovePlayer()
{
Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 forward = orientation.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Vector3 right = orientation.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);

        float curSpeedX = moveSpeed + bhopSpeed;
        float moveX = isGrounded ? curSpeedX * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : (curSpeedX / 2 * horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        float moveZ = isGrounded ? curSpeedX * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : (curSpeedX / 2 * verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    
        moveDirection = (forward * moveX) + (right * moveZ);
        moveDirection.y = 0;
    
        float verticalVelocity = rb.velocity.y;
    
        rb.velocity = moveDirection;
    
        Vector3 newVelocity = rb.velocity;
        newVelocity.y = verticalVelocity;
        rb.velocity = newVelocity;
    }
```

I'm a beginner in unity, here's my code, I'll describe the problem in detail now.
The problem is that my movement code works the way I want it to, but if I try to call the
say :

```
           if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.forward * 5000, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            }
```

then it just teleports the player, I realize this is because of the forced velocity change, but I need to change it to move the player correctly, while I need addforce for other manipulations.
How do i solve this problem?

I'm not quite sure what can be done about it or how to fix it even in theory.